# mysql dynamic auto updating calculated row

Tags: mysql, dynamic, calculated-columns

I'm looking for the following! I have a table of residences, each residence has an ID that corresponds to a district it is in. I have a table of districts with the ID, NAme and a count of residences. What I would like is for the count of residences per district to dynamically update as residences are moved from district to district. I understand I will need a trigger to force the update, but I'm not sure what I need it to be, nor do I understand how to

`INSERT INTO District.resCount SUM(Select * FROM residences R WHERE R.dID = District.ID);`

on a regular interval.

Comment: I understand you are wanting this number to be added, but have you considered just running this SUM query each time you need this count? To help you answer this specific question, please tell me what you are using for a database? MySQL, Microsoft SQL, DB2, etc. Also, on a regular interval, you are wanting this count updated frequently?

Comment: You need a trigger but dont need `insert`, you need `update`. Also why you need a calculated value in your table, is a waste of space and resources calculate that every time that change. Is easy include the calculation in your returning query.

Comment: while I understand it is a resource hog, it is something I need readily available. I'm full time here and cant spend 5 minutes each day running a report for my boss. This is just easier.

@BrianGerhards MySQL, regular interval being once a day preferably when no one is in the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL,
Try this:

```
SET @districtID = 'some_id'
SET @rescount = Select count(*) FROM residences WHERE dID = @districtID

INSERT INTO District (ID, rescount)  values ( @districtID,  @rescount);
```

Or you can use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_district AFTER INSERT ON residences
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN            
        SET @rescount = Select count(*) FROM residences WHERE dID = NEW.dID
        UPDATE District  SET rescount = @rescount WHERE districtID = NEW.dID
    END;
```

Comment: This will only do it once though, correct? I do appreciate the answer, but am not sure it does exactly what I need.

Comment: I'll try this out today in my test environment and mark as the solution soon. My schedule is kinda busy today so it may take a day or two! Thanks much for the information!

Comment: Went with a different method, but this did work in the end.